# React bootstrap Carousels component not working up getting error

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

React-bootstrap Carousels not working

import React from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap';

class HomeSlider extends React.component {
    render() {
        return(

#### First slide label

Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.

```
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
            alt="Third slide"
          />

          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    );
}
```

}
export default HomeSlider;

Failed to compile
./src/components/HomeSlider.js
Attempted import error: 'react-bootstrap' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Carousel').
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import like this:

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
```

Answer (score 0):

or using src= {**require**("./images/img.JPG")}

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: reference of img in bootstrap5 we write like this, i write like this and is works

Comment: The explanation isnt for me. It was a suggestion to improve your answer. otherwise the bot may delete it